# redux-saga, как дождаться получения данных?

Tags: reactjs, redux, асинхронность, saga

Допустим есть saga, которая получает с сервера какие-то данные. У нас есть компонент, в котором мы делаем `this.props.getData()`, и потом смотрим `this.props.data.name !== ''`.Или какие-то другие проверки с этими данными, как удостовериться что в `this.props.data` уже новые полученные данные, а не старые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить loading status в стейт.

Например, определить четыре состояния - `LOADING`, `SUCCESS`, `ERROR` и `WAIT` (названия любые).

- До отправки запроса (initial state) `loadingStatus` будет `WAIT`
- При инициализации запроса менять loadingStatus на LOADING - при этом статусе отображаем какой нибудь индикатор загрузки
- Когда ответ получен, проставляем статус в зависимости от результата (SUCCESS/ERROR) и отображаем сам результат.

Таким образом приложение не будет полагаться на наличие данных в стейте и будет понятно, загружаются ли новые данные.